# Reproject all shapefiles in same folder in same projection with raster?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have 4 shapefiles in the same folder names like that (1996.shp, 2000.shp, 2006.shp, 2014.shp) and one raster.

I need to reproject all shapfiles in the same projection (4326) of raster, but I do it for one shapefile that it script :

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal

    #tif with projections I want
    tif = gdal.Open("D:/projetp/NDVI.tif")

    #shapefile with the from projection
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    dataSource =   driver.Open("C:/projetp/shape/1996.shp", 1)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

    #set spatial reference and transformation
    sourceprj = layer.GetSpatialRef()
    targetprj = osr.SpatialReference(wkt = tif.GetProjection())
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceprj, targetprj)

    to_fill = ogr.GetDriverByName("Esri Shapefile")
    ds = to_fill.CreateDataSource("C:/projetp/shape/1996poly.shp")
    outlayer = ds.CreateLayer('', targetprj, ogr.wkbPolygon)
    outlayer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))

    #apply transformation

    i = 0
    for feature in layer:
        transformed = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        transformed.Transform(transform)

        geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(transformed.ExportToWkb())
        defn = outlayer.GetLayerDefn()
        feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
        feat.SetField('id', i)
        feat.SetGeometry(geom)
        outlayer.CreateFeature(feat)
        i += 1
        feat = None

    ds = None
```

How can I execute the script for all shapefiles in the folder?

I'm new in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your code into one function (e.g. reprojectShape) and then call it from another function which reads files within folder where shapefiles are located. Here is the code:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
import os

def reprojectShape(fullPath, filename):
  #tif with projections I want
  tif = gdal.Open("D:/projetp/NDVI.tif")

  #shapefile with the from projection
  driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
  dataSource =   driver.Open(fullPath + filename, 1)
  layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

  #set spatial reference and transformation
  sourceprj = layer.GetSpatialRef()
  targetprj = osr.SpatialReference(wkt = tif.GetProjection())
  transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceprj, targetprj)

  to_fill = ogr.GetDriverByName("Esri Shapefile")
  ds = to_fill.CreateDataSource(fullPath + 'reprojected/' + filename)
  outlayer = ds.CreateLayer('', targetprj, ogr.wkbPolygon)
  outlayer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger))

  #apply transformation

  i = 0
  for feature in layer:
    transformed = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    transformed.Transform(transform)

    geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(transformed.ExportToWkb())
    defn = outlayer.GetLayerDefn()
    feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
    feat.SetField('id', i)
    feat.SetGeometry(geom)
    outlayer.CreateFeature(feat)
    i += 1
    feat = None

  ds = None

def reprojectAll():
  folderShape = "C:/projetp/shape/"
  for filename in os.listdir(folderShape):
    if filename.endswith('.shp'):
      reprojectShape(folderShape, filename)
```

Comment: Vranic thank you , but in the fullpath and filname what i need to do ?

Comment: `def reprojectShape(fullPath, filename):
  #tif with projections I want
  tif = gdal.Open("D:/projetp/NDVI.tif")

  #shapefile with the from projection
  driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
  dataSource =   driver.Open(fullPath + filename, 1)
  layer = dataSource.GetLayer()` need to defined path like that path=('C:/projetp/shape/1996.shp") and filename=("1996.shp") ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are tools to directly reproject your shapefiles (not feature by feature), e.g. ogr2ogr

```
import subprocess, glob
ogr2ogrpath = "C:\\Users\\maj\\Anaconda3\\Library\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe" #local path provided in the comments
for shp in glob.glob("D:/projetp/shape/*shp"):#list all shapefiles in a folder
    subprocess.call([ogr2ogrpath, "-t_srs", "EPSG:4326", shp.replace("projetp/shape","reprojected"), shp]) #remark, you might need to give full path to your ogr2ogr.exe (if ogr2ogr.exe isnot in your PATH list)
```

Comment: thank you  i can use you script to do the same work to my script or i need add your script ?

Comment: my script will do the same job as your script, except that I do not select the coordiante system dynamically based on a given image (EPSG:4326 is hardcoded). You can use what you did in your script to get your targetprj and replace my "EPSG:4326" with targetprj if you need a dynamic projection

Comment: ` #remark, you might need to give full path to your ogr2ogr.exe (if ogr2ogr.exe isnot in your PATH list)` i don't understand what i need to do in path

Comment: I am not using the API but I use subprocess to run a command line. If you have the API, you must have the ogr2ogr binary file installed somewhere on you computer. If you installed ogr2OGR using OSGEO4W, for instance, run this script from within the OSGEO4W command prompt will work. Otherwise, you must find where it is located and write its full path (e.g. C:/osgeo/bin/ogr2ogr.exe)

Comment: i'm using spyder anaconda i don't know how do that

Comment: try to search ogr2ogr.exe in windows explorer

Comment: i find the directory her : C:\Users\maj\Anaconda3\Library\bin !

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should work now.

Comment: i turn the script but i don't know why i don't have resultat the shapfiles is the same !!!

Comment: `for shp in glob.glob("D:/projetp/shape/*.shp")`  or `like that  for shp in glob.glob("D:/projetp/shape/*shp")` the . before shp or not ? thank u